# Generating OpenCL C code

Tags: plotting, dynamic, complex, code-generation, opencllink

I'm trying to make an interactive complex function plotter using OpenCl. So far I can only plot functions that I hardcode into the kernel by hand. I'd like to be able to use `ComplexExpand@#@f@(x + I*y) & /@ {Re, Im}`, where f is some complex function as a string, to generate a string of code that can then be can be inserted into the plotting kernel and compiled. I tried porting over Times, Plus, Power, and the FullForm functions to the OpenCL kernel; this barely works though since OpenCL doesn't allow for function to have a variable number of arguments while Mathematica does. Any pointers/solutions would be much appreciated. Also, am I going about this correctly, or is there a better way to pass variable functions to a kernel?